# Retrieving apps and Music from 2 iCloud accounts to one iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, music

I have 2 iCloud accounts. not because of any crafty idea or security concerns but because I forgot my password and it was easier to just setup anther account.

Now I just upgraded my phone to a 5S and want to get all my apps and music on the new phone but they're backed up on two accounts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The apps are not « backed up » on account, they are at most link to an account.

Your only solution :

- If you still have your first password : Change your iTunes login in the iPhone and download the apps linked to that account. You'll get the cloud icon on the App Store if the app is linked, a price/free else.
- You do the same thing with the second account.

NB:  If you really forgot your password, you're going to need to rebuy the apps with your new account.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the first answer.

I attempted to update my Apple ID with a new email address and ended up creating a second account, and then purchased a movie. I didn't discover my error until I opened iTunes and discovered all my iPhone apps were gone.

If you can remember your original Apple ID password, you can change the iTunes ID and download all your purchases, and then change back to the other account if you need to.

Apple's password recovery method surely tries your patience.